# s:iterator over Map with a dynamic key parameter

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have a problem with the inner iterator in the following Struts2 JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="thatCompany.tags" var="tagGroups">
  <tr>
     <td><s:property value="#tagGroups.key" /></td><!-- this works nicely! -->
     <td>
    <ul>
     <s:iterator value="{thisCompany.tags['#tagGroups.key']}" var="thisTagGroup">
           <!-- doesn't work, displays one empty LI element -->
           <li> <s:property value="#thisTagGroup.key"/>
      </s:iterator>
    </ul>
      </td>
<!-- snip -->
```

*thisCompany.tags* and *thatCompany.tags* are both of type `Map<String, Map<BigDecimal, String>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, this syntax works:

```
<s:iterator value="thisCompany.tags[#tagGroups.key]" var="foobar">
  <li> <s:property value="#foobar.value"/>
</s:iterator>
```

But this is weird: if I name the variable *thisTagGroup* instead of *foobar* it doesn't work anymore. Is it because *this* is somehow reserved and variable names cannot even begin with *this-*?